# SmartWatch 2 Google Play Licensing

Tags: android, sony, android-lvl, sony-smartwatch

I want to add Google Play Licensing to my smartwatch 2 app.

I would like to know where is the best place to do the license check, since I do not want to do it when the user open the app on the watch since it may slow it down a lot.

I would like to do it when the application is installed/registered, so I checked the onCreate() method of the Extension Service, which is called when the app is registered, but its also called when the app is launched on the watch.

So, which is the best place?

Thanks!!

Comment: "may slow it down a lot" na, license checks are asynchronous

Comment: So it's a good practice to put it on the Control Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

License checks can be done asynchronously. Since the actual extension apk runs on the phone with only UI components communicated to the watch, it will not affect the performance on the watch if done asynchronously. Oncreate() should be the best place to do it. You could do it the very first time when the app starts (use a class to just instantiate at first startup.).